# XML document processing cant load file

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing an application where i need to pull information out of a XML Document.

My XML document is stored in my projects bin/ Debug file.

I cant get it working.

XML document named informationData:

```
<xml>
<information>
<name >stian</name>
<surname>Kruger</surname>
<tel>0825514302</tel>
<photo>1234JLJ.jpg</photo>
</information>
</xml>
```

my call code:

```
private void btnReadXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("informationData.xml");

            XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/information");

            foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
            {
                Name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
                Surname = node.SelectSingleNode("surname").InnerText;
                TelNumber = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("tel").InnerText);

            }
        }
```

Comment: what framework version are you using? Prefer `XDocument` to `XmlDocument`.

Comment: try using XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("information");

Comment: Ca you please post what the exact exception and message are and on what line it is occurring?

Comment: It does not enter the foreach loop, it jumps over it.

Comment: As an aside, the XML specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn) suggests you shouldn't really be using "<xml>" as an element name. I've never actually known it to cause a problem, but the standard says it shouldn't be used: xml, XML, or mixed case variants, are not to be used as the start of element names; strictly speaking.

Answer (score 5):

Your XPath selector is wrong. Replace:

```
XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/information");
```

with:

```
XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//information");
```

or with:

```
XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("information");
```

Also make sure that the XML file is present in the same folder as the running executable (you said `bin/Debug/informationData.xml`). If the XML file is part of your Visual Studio project you could select it and in the properties set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`. This way VS will automatically copy the XML file to this output folder everytime you compile the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<information>
 <name >stian</name>
 <surname>Kruger</surname>
 <tel>0825514302</tel>
 <photo>1234JLJ.jpg</photo>
</information>


 var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("informationData.xml");
 var name = xmlDoc.Element("name").Value;
 var surname = xmlDoc.Element("surname").Value;
 var telNumber = Convert.ToInt32(xmlDoc.Element("tel").Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` as first line in XML file